# How can I use pandas to reformat the table flexibly like using dplyr group_by and do

Tags: pandas

How can I reshape a data frame by group and add the next step in a group to a new column.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
    'step': [1,2,3,1,3,4,1]
})

print(df)
  id  step
0  A     1
1  A     2
2  A     3
3  B     1
4  B     3
5  B     4
6  C     1

# target format
  id  current_step  next_step
0  A     1          2
1  A     2          3
2  A     3          None
3  B     1          3
4  B     3          4
5  B     4          None
6  C     1          None
```

This works fine:

```
df.groupby(['id']).apply(
    lambda df: df.assign(next_step = df['step'].shift(-1))
                        ).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shift your dataframe back by 1 and add these as new columns to populate the next step column like this:

```
df[['id2', 'next_step']] = df[['id', 'step']].shift(-1)

  id  step  id2  next_step
0  A     1    A        2.0
1  A     2    A        3.0
2  A     3    B        1.0
3  B     1    B        3.0
4  B     3    B        4.0
5  B     4    C        1.0
6  C     1  NaN        NaN
```

Then you can check where `id != id2`, and replace those values in next_step with none using `.loc`

```
df.loc[df['id'] != df['id2'], 'next_step'] = None

  id  step  id2  next_step
0  A     1    A        2.0
1  A     2    A        3.0
2  A     3    B        NaN
3  B     1    B        3.0
4  B     3    B        4.0
5  B     4    C        NaN
6  C     1  NaN        NaN
```

Then you can remove the 'id2' column, and rename 'step' to 'current_step' with the below:

```
df = df.drop('id2', axis=1)
df = df.rename(columns={'step':'current_step'})
```

Final output:

```
  id  current_step  next_step
0  A             1        2.0
1  A             2        3.0
2  A             3        NaN
3  B             1        3.0
4  B             3        4.0
5  B             4        NaN
6  C             1        NaN
```

Comment: `def do(df):
    df = df.assign(next_step = df['step'].shift(-1))
    return df

df.groupby(['id']).apply(do).reset_index(drop=True)`
can work. But is there any way to define the function in the lambda expression?

Comment: @John possibly, I'm not very good with lambda expressions so I wouldn't know where to start unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

With [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from datar.all import f, group_by, summarise, lead
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     'id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
...     'step': [1,2,3,1,3,4,1]
... })
>>> 
>>> df >> group_by(f.id) >> summarise(current_step = f.step, next_step = lead(f.step))
[2022-06-20 09:43:04][datar][   INFO] `summarise()` has grouped output by ['id'] (override with `_
groups` argument)
        id  current_step  next_step
  <object>       <int64>  <float64>
0        A             1        2.0
1        A             2        3.0
2        A             3        NaN
3        B             1        3.0
4        B             3        4.0
5        B             4        NaN
6        C             1        NaN
[TibbleGrouped: id (n=3)]
```